# WSDL soap webservice in Android, error 404

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

I have a wsdl url written for android to consume some soap web services. I used the wsdl2code.com to generate the classes from the wsdl URL. I added the class to my project folder in eclipse and call the method (which is used for registration purpose of the user) Register from the generated class.

**The problem occurs here, calling the httptrasportSE.call method I am receiving a 404 error. Does anybody have any idea about this situation.**

I have already tested the webservise with the wsdl service tester
 wcfstorm.com testing environment. It's working fine there.

I think the error is some where in the class that which where I am calling the service via KSOAP. But I failed to find it out.

Comment: Any one before downvoting a question pls provide a reason. Please don't down vote the question because of that you have no Idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 means that the web service you are trying to access couldn't be found.

Make sure that you have the correct namespace, soap service URL and method name. You can also use Soap UI as a tunnel.

I.e. android sends the request to Soap UI and soap UI passes the request on to your soap service. You will then be able to see what is sent to the server and what is returned.

Comment: The wsdl code generated were had itself the url and namespace, Now I changed the url and getting a 201 error, Now I can call the webservice. eg. Registering is working but due to some IOException I can't get the result. Do you have anu idea, to get rid of this IOException?
Thank You.

Comment: You would have to post the code and the error that is causing the IO exception. IO exceptions are usually caused however by either the file you are trying to read or write to doesn't exist or you do not have permission to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You @Boardy, 
I find out the problem. For some unknown reasons the generated java class files contain WRONG service URL. I was fully ignored that possibility before because it is auto generated from the wsdl code so I never think the generated code contains an Error.

But when I changed the url ( I used to test the ksoap service using a damn good TOOLS **WCFSTORM** from there I found out the difference in the url in my class and showing in the WCFSTORM.

When I changed the url it is working fine.
So I am posting this answer because this will help some others.

TIP : Always try some other possible tools and methods apart fromyou have known or own.